# PL/SQL procedure with n numbers of parameter of nested table type

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am currently working on an assignment to create a procedure that will allow user input information like `customerID`, product code etc as shown in the codes. The procedure should be capable of accepting these parameters 'n' times which explains why I created a table of the type. I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I'm having a compiled procedure but with errors.

Please I really need someone to bail me out... :(

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE placeOrder_typ AS OBJECT
    (
        customerID          NUMBER(4,0),
        itemNo              NUMBER(4,0),
        itemQuan            INTEGER,
        deliveryAddress     address_typ
    )
    /
    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE placeOrder_tbltyp IS TABLE OF placeOrder_typ
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_placeOrder (p_placeOrder_tbl IN placeOrder_tbltyp)
        IS
        BEGIN
            FOR i IN 1..p_placeOrder_tbl.COUNT LOOP

            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_placeOrder_tbl(i).customerID||' Customer No '||
                                p_placeOrder_tbl(i).itemNo||' Product No '||
                                p_placeOrder_tbl(i).itemQuan||' Quantity '||
                                p_placeOrder_tbl(i).deliveryAddress||' Delivery Address ');

            END LOOP;
        END;


    DECLARE
    placeOrder_var placeOrder_tbltyp := placeOrder_tbltyp();

        BEGIN
            placeOrder_var.extend;
            placeOrder_var(1).customerID := 0001;
            placeOrder_var(1).itemNo := 0001;
            placeOrder_var(1).itemQuan := 2;
            placeOrder_var(1).deliveryAddress := address_typ('3 Cross Road', 'Sunderland', 'SU2 6ZA');

            placeOrder_var.extend;
            placeOrder_var(2).customerID := 0002;
            placeOrder_var(2).itemNo := 0001;
            placeOrder_var(2).itemQuan := 15;
            placeOrder_var(2).deliveryAddress := address_typ('3 Cross Road', 'Sunderland', 'SU2 6ZA');

            p_placeOrder (p_placeOrder_tbl => placeOrder_var);
        END;
    /
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've proper `address_typ`
I've made a sample as
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE address_typ IS OBJECT
     (
          val1 VARCHAR2(20),
          val2 VARCHAR2(20),
          val3 VARCHAR2(20)
     );
```

Now,

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE placeOrder_typ FORCE AS OBJECT
    (
        customerID          NUMBER(4,0),
        itemNo              NUMBER(4,0),
        itemQuan            INTEGER,
        deliveryAddress     address_typ
    );

    CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE placeOrder_tbltyp IS TABLE OF placeOrder_typ;

CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE p_placeOrder(
          p_placeOrder_tbl IN placeOrder_tbltyp)
IS
BEGIN
     FOR i IN 1..p_placeOrder_tbl.COUNT
     LOOP
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_placeOrder_tbl(i).customerID||' Customer No ');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_placeOrder_tbl(i).itemNo||' Product No ');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_placeOrder_tbl(i).itemQuan||' Quantity ');
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_placeOrder_tbl(i).deliveryAddress.val1||' Delivery Address ');
     END LOOP;
END;
```

Please note: 
To display type field , you need to use the column name .

```
DECLARE
     placeOrder_var placeOrder_tbltyp := NEW placeOrder_tbltyp();
BEGIN
     placeOrder_var.EXTEND;
     placeorder_var(1) := placeOrder_typ(1, 2,3, address_typ('3 Cross Road', 'Sunderland', 'SU2 6ZA'));
     p_placeOrder (p_placeOrder_tbl => placeOrder_var);
END;
/
```

output:

```
anonymous block completed
1 Customer No 
2 Product No 
3 Quantity 
3 Cross Road Delivery Address
```

Comment: thanks so much, i've got it working but how do i display the values for the customerID, itemNo, itemQuan and also the full deliveryAddress?

Comment: you may use the same method viz, p_placeOrder_tbl(i).deliveryAddress.val2, p_placeOrder_tbl(i).deliveryAddress.val3 etc..